# The resolvent of a differentation operator on $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Consider a densely defined operator $A : C[a,b ]\rightarrow C[a,b ]$, 
$$Au=u^{\prime}$$
with domain
$$D(A)= \{ u\in C^1[a,b]: u(b)=ku(a)  \}$$
 for some $k>0$.

I have to find $R_A(\lambda)$ for $k\neq  1$, it looks like the sum of two integrals.

But how to find $R_A(\lambda)$ for $k=1$. I cannot find an idea to present it as integral. Maybe I need to use Neumann series, but I cannot prove that $\|A\|<1$.

Comment: For $\lambda\in\rho(A)$, the function $g=R_{A}(\lambda)f$ is the unique solution of $(A-\lambda I)g=f$, which means $g'-\lambda g= f$ and $g(a)=g(b)$. For a fixed $\lambda$: If you cannot solve for $g$ given a general $f$, then $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$.

Comment: I edited the question and title, replacing $L^2$ with $C[a,b]$ in the title to bring it in line with the actual question.